# Query inside a query in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
update tbl_user set tbl_user.Zoneid='(Select tbl_timezone.Zoneid from tbl_timezone where tbl_timezone.timezone='[UTC - 4:30] Venezuelan Standard Time')' Where tbl_user.userid='1'
```

I get this error when i run the above query

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[UTC - 4:30] Venezuelan Standard Time')' Where tbl_user.userid='1'' at line 1

but when I execute

```
 update tbl_user set tbl_user.Zoneid='10' Where tbl_user.userid='1';
```

then it works fine

the result of following query is 10.

```
Select tbl_timezone.Zoneid from tbl_timezone where tbl_timezone.timezone='[UTC - 4:30] Venezuelan Standard Time'
```

whats wrong with my first query. why am I getting error

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove quotes :

```
update tbl_user set tbl_user.Zoneid=(Select tbl_timezone.Zoneid from tbl_timezone where tbl_timezone.timezone='[UTC - 4:30] Venezuelan Standard Time') Where tbl_user.userid='1'
```

Answer (score 1):

In all SQL dialects, single quotes are used to delimiter strings:

```
SELECT this_is_a_column, 'This is a literal string'
FROM table
```

Additionally, there're escaping mechanism so you can write a string that contains single quotes

```
SELECT 'This string contains \'single\' quotes'
```

In your case:

- You pretend to write code inside a string, thus is will never be executed as such.
- You write unquoted single quotes inside a string, thus you get a syntax error.